# c# casting to and from interface types with generic types

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I have class `MockRepository` which implements interface `IRepository` and I have a class `Technology` which implements interface `IIdentifiable`.

I want to cast an object from `MockRepository<Technology>` to `IRepository<IIdentifiable>` and also cast back again after some operations are complete. Is this possible? my code compiles but when i try to run it i get an invalid cast exception.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: To clarify @antonijn 's question, why do you need to cast these objects? `MockRepository` is already `IRepository`, so you get all the `IRepository` functionality, and `Technology` is `IIdentifiable`, so you get that interface implementation as well. Perhaps if you show us how you are using them and what you are trying to accomplish with this conversion, we could help you more.

Comment: Usually you could use `MockRepository<Technology>` in all cases where you would want to cast to `IRepository<IIdentifyable>`, it should work without casting first. If there's another reason to cast this, please provide some code to clarify your question.

Comment: to pass it as a parameter to a function that takes `IRepository<IIdentifiable>` as an argument type. if I define the argument type to be `MockRepository<Technology>` then I can't use it for the actual repository object and other identifiable objects that we get from repositories

Comment: Question must include relevant code bits and complete error messages. As it is, it's very difficult to answer properly. Class definitions would help. Keep in mind though that generic collections are not interchangeable, so <Technology> and <IIdentifiable> make up for two distinct collection types.

Comment: See the bottom of my answer for an example how you can create the function call you require

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is no.

If you have an interface `IMyInterface<T>` then the compiler will create a new interface for each type of T that you use and substitute for all values of T.

To give an example:

I have an interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T> {
   public T Value {get; set;}
}
```

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Foo {}

public class Bar : Foo {}
```

I then define the following

```
public class Orange : IMyInterface<Foo> {}

public class Banana : IMyInterface<Bar> {}
```

The compiler will automatically create 2 new interfaces using a specific name convention, I'm going to use different names to highlight that they are different

```
public interface RandomInterface {
   Foo Value { get; set; }
}

public interface AlternativeInterface {
   Bar Value { get; set; }
}

public class Orange : RandomInterface {
}

public class Banana : AlternativeInterface {
}
```

As you can see there is no relationship between `RandomInterface` and `AlternativeInterface`. So a class inheriting from `RandomInterface` cannot be cast to `AlternativeInterface`

**UPDATE AFTER READING QUESTION COMMENTS**

If you wish to pass MockRepository to a function that expects IRepository you can do the following

```
 public void MyFunction<T>(IRepository<T> repo) where T: IIdentifiable {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you have:

```
class MockRepository<T> : IRepository<T>  // note: same T
{
}

interface IRepository<out X>  // note: "out" means covariance in X
{
}
```

Then because a `Technology` is an `IIdentifiable`, covariance gives that an `IRepository<Technology>` is also an `IRepository<IIdentifiable>`.

So if your `IRepository<>` interface is (or can be made) covariant, it should work.